# Способы выражения подлежащего

Tags: подлежащее

Если рядом стоит существительное в Им.п, обозначающее звание,род занятий, профессию и т.п. и имя собственное в Им.п., будет ли это все подлежащим? Например:
Князь Юрий Долгорукий подошёл к окну. Здесь подлежащее "князь Юрий Долгорукий" или просто "князь"?

Answer (score 2):

Юрий Долгорукий - подлежащее, князь - определение. Изучите тему "Приложение - имя собственное" и "Приложение - имя нарицательное". В данном случае в роли подлежащего выступает имя собственное.
Доктор наук Званцева вышла из аудитории. Званцева - подлежащее. Согласуется со сказуемым (ж.р.!).

Comment: А какой вопрос надо задать к слову  "князь"? В школе очень любят задавать вопросы ко всем членам предложения.  И каком тексте можно использовать такое предложение: Князь Юрий Долгорукий подошёл к окну. Почему я спрашиваю? Просто бывают контекстуально несвободные сочетания, которые являются единым членом предложения.  Может, это цельное выражение, с титулом перед именем?

Comment: Спасибо, но непонятно. У меня же КОНКРЕТНЫЕ вопросы:  (1) Какой вопрос задать при разборе от подлежащего к приложению/определению.  Юрий Долгорукий какой? какой именно или что? (2) Может ли  "Князь Юрий Долгорукий" быть подлежащим как цельное сочетание в каком-либо тексте.  Вот пример: Князь Болконский был небольшого роста, весьма красивый молодой человек с определенными и сухими чертами.  Болконский (какой?) князь, так разбирать?

Comment: Сравнить: "На собрании учитель Иванов спросил..."   Здесь все понятно. Иванов (какой именно)? Учитель. Это приложение/определение. А там все-таки князь, на титул похоже.   Текст романа: " Однако, как обыкновенно, в девятом часу князь вышел гулять в своей бархатной шубке с собольим воротником и такой же шапке".  Здесь титул в роли подлежащего.